# Word for expressing a mix of happiness and frustration

Tags: single-word-request, phrase-request

I was just wondering if such a word exists in German, does anybody know?
A mix of happiness and frustration.

Context: I have a job to do, I will be happy when it is done but in the meantime I feel frustrated because it's a complicated and annoying task.

Comment: What makes you believe that such a word might exist in German language? Is there any other language that has such a word?

Comment: Welcome to German Language SE. Can you please [edit] your question to specify: 1) In what context would you want to use that word and what exactly do you want to express. Where does that dissonance of feelings come from? 2) Do you know a similar word/phrase in another language? If yes, what does a dictionary suggest and why does it not satisfy you?

Comment: @Hubert I have no idea, I was just wondering since German has a lot of words to express feelings that are not found in other languages.

Comment: Thank you for your edit. Unfortunately, I am confused now. In the situation you describe, you would be first frustrated and then happy, not both at the same time. Or are you happy anticipating that you will have finished the job?

Comment: Yeah something like that, like really wanting to get something done because the result will make me happy, however also having to go though the pain of doing it.

Comment: You can always make up new compounds from existing ones, especially when they are nouns. *Erfolgsfrust*, *Erfolgsfreudenerreichungsfrust*, ...

Comment: very happy & very depressed (=not really frustation): Himmelhoch jauchzend, zu Tode betrübt = up one minute - down the next (dict.cc). I thought of a similiar one. Well, you have to "durchbeißen" until you did it. Maybe you should look for "how to describe the joy of finishing while the necessary doing is frustrating"? - just to point out the context.

Answer (score 2):

You could say "in den sauren Apfel beißen". It is used to indicate that one decided to do something one does not really want to do, but it may still be worth it or necessary at least. "Sich einen Ruck geben" might be an expression that may fit your description, it basically means pulling oneself together. But both of these refer to the start of the task, not the time during which it is completed. Essentially, they both describe the moment in which you get moving and start working.